# Can't create a new angular project

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Tried creating a new angular Project using,

```
ng new Project
```

All the files are created, just the node modules folder isn't created and it ends with this message

```
⠧ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...1.0.30000656","del-cl'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shashank/.npm/_logs/2020-08-18T13_48_27_002Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
```

As suggested I tried,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and

```
npm install
```

The issue still stays...

Comment: Could you add the debug log? From `/home/shashank/.npm/_logs/2020-08-18T13_48_27_002Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would require further information to proceed troubleshooting, but what you can try to do is:

1. Delete manually directory `npm` and `npm-cache` in `../AppData/Roaming`
2. Run in your terminal `npm cache clean --force`
3. Install your package with `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the console is opened with admin rights