# WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to install angular/cli using `npm install -g @angular/cli`
and it keeps sending me warnings

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\amsmk\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\amsmk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@10.0.7 postinstall C:\Users\amsmk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@10.0.7
added 281 packages from 206 contributors in 74.68s
```

How can I fix this

Comment: You can't. Only the `@angular/cli` maintainers can fix this. There is no impact for you: a deprecated package does not stop working.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. (Refresh all your dependencies)

1. clear your node cache files.
   Delete these folders `npm` and `npm-cache` in `../AppData/Roaming`
2. Globally install your angular CLI again.
   npm install -g @angular/cli

References ::

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/folders

[Can't create a new angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470327/cant-create-a-new-angular-project)

Answer (score 1):

Migrate your test framework from protractor to other framework (I prefer cypress) and then uninstall protractor from your project then deprecated `request` and `har-validator` will get resolved.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor?activeTab=versions, https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-end-to-end-testing-with-angular-d175f751cb9c, https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/protractor-to-cypress#Getting-Started)

Step1:
Install cypress using following command

```
ng add @cypress/schematic
```

Step2:
Migrate all your tests cypress

Step3:
Uninstall protractor using following command

```
npm uninstall protractor
```

Then remove the node_modules and package-lock.json file

Step4:
install the node_modules again with following command

```
npm i or npm install
```

Now deprecated warnings will get resolved and removed from the project

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this command

```
npm install --no-fund -g <name>
```